# Meteor support developing on Windows

Tags: node.js, meteor

Does Meteor support developing on Windows? I did not see any downloads or mention of Windows in the docs.

The "Quick Start" assumes you are on *Nix OS.

Comment: November 2014: there is an [official Windows support preview](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows).

Answer (score 54):

Meteor 1.1+: official Windows support launched on https://win.meteor.com/

Meteor 1.0+: there is an [official Windows preview](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows).

Meteor 0.8 and older: see http://win.meteor.com/

---

[image]

Proof, Meteor running on Windows.

Comment: So, Node 0.6.18 is out now, is it just a case of writing an install script, or is there more to do?

Comment: @TonyBlundell: Made a MSI installer that will be pulled into Meteor later, see my post.

Comment: Is there a place (other than this SO question) that tracks work for meteor-on-Windows?  Just trying to avoid duplication of effort or questions :)

Comment: @JamesManning: MSI in this answer is still up-to-date, as I go on a vaction within half a week there might be a delay on the setup of next version. As for tracking effort, see commits to https://github.com/TomWij/meteor-windows or the Windows pull request at the Meteor repo.

Comment: For a later release of meteor for windows, please try: https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/wiki/Windows

Answer (score 30):

**Edit:** See [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540448/1269037).

Old answer below.

---

No, this is not yet supported on windows. If you try to install in you will receive the following error:

```
Sorry, this OS is not supported yet.
```

As a workaround you can run a linux box in a VM and use that as a server to run meteor but still do all development from within windows. I've done this using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu with no GUI. Here's the steps:

1. Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
2. Grab [Ubuntu ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)
3. Setup Ubuntu VM using VirtualBox (just follow the wizard steps)
4. Install samba on VM to enable file access from windows. This [article](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-access-ubuntu-shared-folders-windows-7) was a great help.
5. Install ssh using Ubuntu Software Center. [This](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/09/connect-ubuntu-10-0410-10-maverick-meerkat-secure-shell-ssh/) was helpful.
6. Shutdown VM and run from a DOS prompt using vboxheadless -startvm "VM Name"
7. You can then use a ssh client (I'm using cygwin) to connect to the box to run commands e.g. ssh user@box_ip_address
8. Can browse and edit files using windows file share e.g. \\box_ip_address\share
9. Can run meteor apps within local browser, just replace the localhost in the address that meteor assigns with the ip address of the box.

Comment: Wow sorry, my bad! I must have misclicked and didn't notice until now. I'd remove it if I could, but it's locked in until your answer is edited. :/

Comment: No problem. Was just curious about why I got downvoted twice.

Comment: Hm... I am having problems running meteor in the share on the linux box. Could this be a permissions issue:  
    root@ubuntu-dev:/media/sf_Flexy/FlexyMatch# meteor  
    [[[[[ /media/sf_Flexy/FlexyMatch ]]]]]  
    
    Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.  
    Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.  
    Initializing mongo database... this may take a moment.  
    Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.  
    Can't start mongod. Check for other processes listening on port 3002 or other meteors running in the same project.

Comment: Ah, edit of the previous comment lasted for 5 mins, so I have to post a followup, sorry guys. 
A copy on the linux box of the share-contents works fine, using root as user/group. BTW: Noth attempts were using root as process owner.

Comment: Ok. For someone else bumping into this: I was using the sharing built into VirtualBox. Don't do that. Create a shared folder on the linux box and use that from the windows box instead. Thanks for your good steps that pointed me to an alternative wy of doing things @chris

Comment: In the meantime, meteor has support for Windows - http://win.meteor.com. Any chance you could update your answer, so new users get the right picture?

Comment: @ChrisHerring please make the guide more dummy-friendly :-/

Answer (score 5):

I just tried to install it with `curl` on Windows 7, and got:

```
Sorry, this OS is not supported yet.
```

Comment: In the meantime, meteor has support for Windows - http://win.meteor.com. Any chance you could update your answers, so new users get the right picture?

Answer (score 5):

**A substantial update as the existing answers to this question are very out of date.**

---

Official Windows support can be found at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows

Unofficial Windows support for Meteor can be found on [http://win.meteor.com/](http://win.meteor.com)

There are 3 solutions outlined on win.meteor.com, one native MSI installer, and 2 virtualized solutions based on Vagrant:

1) MSI Installer:

> Stephen Darnell has picked up where Tom Wijsman graciously left off.
>   This solution is the most straight forward way to get Meteor running
>   on Windows with an MSI Installer provided. There are some trade-offs
>   because this is a fork and can lag behind the latest version as
>   Stephen can update to and test the latest version.

2) Vagrant Shell Provisioning

> Gabriel Pugliese has posted a guide for how to provision Meteor on
>   Linux with Vagrant's Shell Provisioning. These may be more accessible
>   to users familier with Linux and Shell scripts. This solution is
>   easier to tweak through the straight forward shell commands than the
>   Chef alternative.

3) Vagrant Chef Provisioning

> Matthew Sullivan is maintaining a set of Vagrant files, Chef cookbook,
>   and guide for provisioning Meteor on Linux with Vagrant. This Chef
>   solution is a slightly more automated and configurable than the shell
>   solution, however likely not as simple to tweak beyond the provided
>   configuration parameters as the Shell solution.

GitHub Repos and details can be found on [win.meteor.com](http://win.meteor.com).  The three authors are very responsive on the [Meteor-talk Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/meteor-talk).

---

**A bit of history:**

Unofficial Windows support for Meteor was started by Tom Wijsman, and was supported by Tom until 0.5.9.  Versions 0.6.0 and later are by Stephen Darnell, Gabriel Pugliese, and Matt Sullivan.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see [Nitrous.io](http://www.nitrous.io) mentioned here.

I am using Nitrous.io together with [Nitrous Desktop](https://www.nitrous.io/desktop#windows), which allows you to use your favourite text editor (in my case, Sublime Text).

There is a quick tutorial [here](http://youtu.be/Y6WANmBe1Tk) and [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) also deals with this in chapter 2.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Windows is not supported yet. If you want to play with it, I would suggest grabbing [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and installing your favorite flavor of Linux on it.

Comment: Or do a pseudo-dual boot of Ubuntu with the Wubi installer: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer.  Waaaaaay better than a virtual box (IMHO).

Comment: In the meantime, meteor has support for Windows - http://win.meteor.com. Any chance you could update your answers, so new users get the right picture?

Comment: Ping? Pretty please update or delete the answer since it's now obsolete? You'll keep the reputation.

Answer (score 1):

1. I downloaded the above .msi installer and installed to `c:\Meteor`
2. Add the  `c:\Meteor` directory you just made to your PATH environment variable.
3. Run the following command: npm install Meteor-Test-Installer
4. Add the `C:\Meteor\bin\node_modules\npm\bin` directory you just made to your PATH environment variable.

Log below from my DOS screen:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\mike>cd\

C:\>cd meteor

C:\Meteor>cd C:\Meteor\bin\node_modules\npm\bin

C:\Meteor\bin\node_modules\npm\bin>meteor create try-meteor
try-meteor: created.

To run your new app:
cd try-meteor
meteor

C:\Meteor\bin\node_modules\npm\bin>curl
‘curl’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Meteor\bin\node_modules\npm\bin>cd try-meteor

C:\Meteor\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\try-meteor>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Meteor\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\try-meteor ]]]]]

Initializing mongo database… this may take a moment.
Running on: http://localhost:3000/
```

Open `http://localhost:3000/` in broswer ... Voila !!

Hello World!

Welcome to try-meteor.

Comment: Please note that Meteor-Test-Installer no longer exists, use http://win.meteor.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you get error like this below :

```
{
[[[[[ D:\sms\Apps\Meteor\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\try-meteor ]]]]]

Unexpected mongo exit code 127. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 127. Restarting.
////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////

meteor is out of date. Please run:

     meteor update

////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////
Unexpected mongo exit code 127. Restarting.
Can't start mongod. Check for other processes listening on port 3002 or other me
teors running in the same project.
}
```

Update the MondoDB folder with the latest mogodb files from the mongodb site.

Comment: This is no longer necessary, this was due to a 64-bit Mongo, use http://win.meteor.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that new coders who are also new to Meteor might have installed it correctly, but are having trouble figuring out how to open and run it.  So I'll just address that issue in this post.

1) I assume you went here: http://win.meteor.com/ and downloaded the MSI installer

2) I assume you then created a *newapp* in meteor and then ran meteor

3) If steps 1 & 2 are complete, you should see this in your command line:

Initializing mongo database... this may take a moment.
=> Meteor server running on: `http://localhost:3000/`

4) Open Chrome and type in the local host address: `http://localhost:3000/`

5) Open your *newapp* folder - should be located in your Meteor folder wherever its installed on your hard drive

6) Open your *newapp.html*, *newapp.css*, and *newapp.js* files in your favorite editor (like Sublime Text 2)

7) Begin editing these files as you like and watch your page automatically update, as Meteor is designed to do.

Voila!!  You're building with Meteor.  Enjoy!!

Comment: Spent all weekend playing around with this...On a windows box, I'm looking at Meteor Release 0.8.3 The standard meteor sample tutorial works fine up until the lesson where we start using a Mongo DB collection. `www.meteor.com/try/3` At that point the entire application crashes hard.  I'm thinking Ubuntu complete OS on usb flash drive for the fix?

Comment: Yeah zipzit, Ubuntu will solve ALL of your problems with Meteor. Although you can run up to Meteor 0.8.4 on Windows, there are a lot of issues that just go away on Linux/Unix systems.  I actually ALWAYS use Ubuntu when working in Meteor. Do this and Meteor becomes a joy to use.

Answer (score 1):

As of two days ago, a preview version is available here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows

Comment: I just tried it, and although my (simple) application seems to compile and run OK (well done to the engineers for that little feat!), application start-up and re-building the application on code change is VERY slow compared to my experience on the same box running Ubuntu 14.04. I shall probably wait a bit longer before switching development to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Recent check of their site and checking their FAQ, you'll find the Meteor Development Roadmap. They host it on Trello and after the 1.0 launch, you'll see "Official Windows Support." So, it's on the map - now we wait!

https://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae

Answer (score 0):

Using linux in VM you probably want meteorite which isn't easy if you are as bad as I am to Linux... Here's how (thank you johntday [Unable to install meteorite on Ubuntu VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067674/unable-to-install-meteorite-on-ubuntu-vm/21068821?noredirect=1#21068821)):

Here are my Install Steps

Update and Upgrade your Ubuntu Depending on how up-to-date your image is, this may take a while.
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Install curl sudo apt-get install curl

Install node http://lucidservices.com/2013/09/17/install-node-on-ubuntu/

Install meteor curl https://install.meteor.com | sh

Install meteorite sudo -H npm install -g meteorite

If you have problems setting a high screen resolution, here's a fix:

http://youtu.be/t36wXUu1UtQ