# Unable to install meteorite on Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, virtualbox, meteorite

I run Win7 and install Ubuntu 12.04.3 in Oracle VM VirtualBox 4.3.6.

First thing I do is try to install meteorite, but get the following error:

```
npm install -g meteorite
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: meteorite
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/rune/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "meteorite"
npm ERR! cwd /home/rune
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: meteorite
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rune/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 14):

Apparently, Meteor installs its own node and npm and you shouldn't mix these with system or other node or npm installations.

I was searching this for a long time and created/destroyed many EC2 instances until I found the solution.

After `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh` simply export the path so your shell can find Meteor's npm:

`export PATH=~/.meteor/tools/latest/bin:$PATH`  does it for `.bash-profile`.

This allowed me to easily install meteorite, without sudo:
`npm install -g meteorite`

I learned this from https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/203

Comment: This is definitely the way to go about things. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dont waste your time upgrading your system.
This method is really works and explains internal structure of meteor.

Answer (score 5):

Here are my Install Steps

1: Update and Upgrade your Ubuntu
Depending on how up-to-date your image is, this may take a while.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

2: Install curl

`sudo apt-get install curl`

3: Install node
   http://lucidservices.com/2013/09/17/install-node-on-ubuntu/

4: Install meteor

`curl https://install.meteor.com | sh`

5: Install meteorite

`sudo -H npm install -g meteorite`

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you very very much. Someone should make a VM-snapshot of this or create script for all this :-)

Comment: This didn't work for me. 

aaron's solution below worked for me and should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me multiple times now - the solution in this thread worked for me - [Install NodeJS on Ubuntu 12.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302436/install-nodejs-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer here: [error when type 'sudo npm install -g meteorite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740284/error-when-type-sudo-npm-install-g-meteorite/19147274#19147274)

Your npm cache needs to be cleaned.

```
rm -rf ~/tmp
sudo npm cache clear
sudo npm install -g meteorite
```