# Instaling meteorite

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm new, forgive me.  I'm trying to install meteorite on my new Linux machine. When attempting to run the install command (with or without root access) I recive this error message:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: meteorite<br>
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12<br>
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)<br>
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)<br>
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)<br>
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)<br>
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)<br>
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)<br>
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)<br>
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)<br>
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)<br>
npm ERR! You may report this log at:<br>
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm><br>
npm ERR! or use<br>
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/jeffrey/npm-debug.log npm<br>
npm ERR! <br>
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-45-generic<br>
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "meteorite"<br>
npm ERR! cwd /home/jeffrey<br>
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12<br>
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4<br>
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: meteorite<br>
npm ERR! <br>
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:<br>
npm ERR!     /home/jeffrey/npm-debug.log<br>
npm not ok<br>
```

Help!

Comment: I assume you're using `npm install meteorite` to install?

Comment: Make sure your node/npm installs are updated. A check of the `https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite` url shows the npm registry data for meteorite, so it's there and ready.

Comment: have you tried: `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite`? It shouldn't be the problem, though. The error seems to regard a failed fetch from the web.

Comment: Same problem here with a different package. Using npm that comes with Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Updating node did the trick! thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from: [Unable to install meteorite on Ubuntu VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067674/unable-to-install-meteorite-on-ubuntu-vm) maybe it will work in your case as well. Your error reminded you of the one I got

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Install curl sudo apt-get install curl

Install node http://lucidservices.com/2013/09/17/install-node-on-ubuntu/

Install meteor curl https://install.meteor.com | sh

Install meteorite sudo -H npm install -g meteorite

Comment: This worked for me, the install of Node was my issue

Answer (score 1):

Doing a default install of node++ as suggested by Rune Jeppesen did not work for me. It turned out that the default node installation for 12.10 is too old.

It worked for me after I installed the latest version of node, instead of the one provided by the default apt-get (from https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```