# Meteor build breaking on deployment to Heroku

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku, reactjs, build

I didn't change any dependencies but suddenly my build is breaking when I deploy to Heroku. See error message below for more information.

````
-----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git... done
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Installing node
-----> Installing meteor
Downloading Meteor distribution
Meteor 1.3 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Now you need to do one of the following:
  (1) Add "$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
  (2) Run this command as root:
        cp "/tmp/buildpack20160403-165-1y59l1z/meteor-j9kn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.3.0_3/mt-os.linux.x86_64/scripts/admin/launch-meteor" /usr/bin/meteor
Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
docs.meteor.com.
-----> Upgrading meteor to METEOR@1.2.1
Installed. Run 'meteor update --release 1.2.1' inside of a particular project
directory to update that project to Meteor 1.2.1.
-----> Bundling bundle
While removing platforms:
error: android: platform is not in this project
-----> Building Meteor with ROOT_URL: https://####.herokuapp.com
npm-container: updating npm dependencies -- scrap, open-graph, future,
react-linkify, externalify, react-modal, react-dom...
=> Errors while initializing project:
While building package npm-container:
error: couldn't install npm packages from npm-shrinkwrap: Command failed: npm
WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No repository
field.
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as
'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.7.0: the module is now available as
'css-select'
npm WARN engine escodegen@1.8.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0"} (current:
{"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm ERR! Error: version not found: ansi-styles@2.2.0
npm ERR!     at
/tmp/buildpack20160403-165-1y59l1z/meteor-j9kn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.11us29f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:125:12
npm ERR!     at saved
(/tmp/buildpack20160403-165-1y59l1z/meteor-j9kn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.11us29f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:167:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
npm ERR! command
"/tmp/buildpack20160403-165-1y59l1z/meteor-j9kn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.11us29f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/tmp/buildpack20160403-165-1y59l1z/meteor-j9kn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.11us29f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"install"
npm ERR! cwd
/tmp/build_99da0b7813d9d5f66b76750d44ec8399/####-af203ae940e85f2aa3e34bfa11a1028cc9cc7c8c/packages/npm-container/.npm/package-new-13b38xe
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! not ok code 0
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No repository
field.
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as
'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.7.0: the module is now available as
'css-select'
npm WARN engine escodegen@1.8.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0"} (current:
{"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm ERR! Error: version not found: ansi-styles@2.2.0
npm ERR!     at
/tmp/buildpack20160403-165-1y59l1z/meteor-j9kn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.11us29f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:125:12
npm ERR!     at saved
(/tmp/buildpack20160403-165-1y59l1z/meteor-j9kn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.11us29f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:167:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
npm ERR! command
"/tmp/buildpack20160403-165-1y59l1z/meteor-j9kn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.11us29f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/tmp/buildpack20160403-165-1y59l1z/meteor-j9kn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.11us29f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"install"
npm ERR! cwd
/tmp/build_99da0b7813d9d5f66b76750d44ec8399/#####-af203ae940e85f2aa3e34bfa11a1028cc9cc7c8c/packages/npm-container/.npm/package-new-13b38xe
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! not ok code 0
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```
````

I'm wondering if this might be a result of all those npm modules being taken down last week. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you do a Google search for 'error: couldn't install npm packages from npm-shrinkwrap: Command failed: npm' it comes up with a lot of stuff. For example this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104909/meteor-fails-cant-install-npm-packages-from-npm-shrinkwrap

Answer (score 1):

The buildpack first installs Meteor 1.3 then checks against your apps's requirement then changes it back to Meteor 1.2. The update/downgrade back to 1.2 does not always resolve dependencies correctly [Cannot downgrade](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6366).  This could be one reason the dependency node version requirements are not being met.  You will need to either resolve the dependency issue locally with 1.3 then deploy using the buildpack, or use a buildpack that installs 1.2.