# Meteor fails. error: couldn't install npm packages from npm-shrinkwrap

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, meteor, npm

I'm new to meteor and both me and my mentor are stumped.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Meteor --version: 1.2.1
node -v: v7.5.0
meteor node -v: v0.10.40
npm -v: 4.1.2
meteor npm -v: 1.4.28

I tried following the advice on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104909/meteor-fails-cant-install-npm-packages-from-npm-shrinkwrap) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo) stackoverflow links, but got the same error. No results with another github link either(sorry, need more reputation to post more links).
Please feel free to ask for any additional info for diagnosis.

> => Started proxy.
>   => Meteor 1.4.3.2 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
>   npm-container: updating npm dependencies -- fibers, path, soap, xml2json, fast-csv, unoconv, aws-sdk, > source-map-support, gm, request, mime,
>   analytics-node, oauth, number-to-words, omit-empty, superagent...
>   => Errors prevented startup:
>
> While building package npm-container:
>      error: couldn't install npm packages from npm-shrinkwrap: Command failed: npm WARN package.json > packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No
>   description
>   npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No repository field.
>   npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No README data
>      npm WARN engine analytics-node@2.0.1: wanted: {"node":">= 0.12.x"} (current: > {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
>   npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: Use uuid module instead
>      npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.1: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/> advisories/130
>   npm WARN engine is-buffer@1.1.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
>   gyp ERR! configure error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.6.0, which is not supported by gyp.
>   gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
>   gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion
>      (/home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:108:14)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at
>      /home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:97:9
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:656:7)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
>   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
>   gyp ERR! command "node"
>      "/home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild"
>   gyp ERR! cwd
>      /home/shrey/projects/steplr-projects/employerapp/packages/npm-container/.npm/package-new-tca2qx/node_modules/> xml2json/node_modules/node-expat
>   gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.40
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
>   gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN deprecated minimatch@3.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>   npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.13 install script.
>   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
>   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
>   npm ERR! command
>      "/home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
>      "/home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
>   "install"
>   npm ERR! cwd /home/shrey/projects/steplr-projects/employerapp/packages/npm-container/.npm/package-new-tca2qx
>   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! not ok code 0
>   npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No description
>   npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No repository field.
>   npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No README data
>      npm WARN engine analytics-node@2.0.1: wanted: {"node":">= 0.12.x"} (current: > {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
>   npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: Use uuid module instead
>      npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.1: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/> advisories/130
>   npm WARN engine is-buffer@1.1.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
>   gyp ERR! configure error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.6.0, which is not supported by gyp.
>   gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
>   gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion
>      (/home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:108:14)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at
>      /home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:97:9
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:656:7)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
>   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
>   gyp ERR! command "node"
>      "/home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild"
>   gyp ERR! cwd
>      /home/shrey/projects/steplr-projects/employerapp/packages/npm-container/.npm/package-new-tca2qx/node_modules/> xml2json/node_modules/node-expat
>   gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.40
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
>   gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN deprecated minimatch@3.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>   npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.13 install script.
>   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
>   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
>   npm ERR! command
>      "/home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
>      "/home/shrey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/> mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
>   "install"
>   npm ERR! cwd /home/shrey/projects/steplr-projects/employerapp/packages/npm-container/.npm/package-new-tca2qx
>   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! not ok code 0
>
> => Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have Python 3 installed, and the npm build needs Python 2